# Rsyslog logging multiple lines(exactly duplicate lines) under messages (Centos - Amazon AMI)

Tags: centos, rsyslog

I am using rsyslog v5 to centralize logs to a server, i see exactly duplicat elogs under /var/log/messages on my log server, although i do not see duplicate lines under distributed servers logs
I am using Amazon AMI-centos

Answer (score 0):

I figuered it out - was monitoring 2 files under each server and was sending them via `*.* @@<%= @log_servers %>:514` twice